# Import CSV codeIgniter 3 - add rule to function if sku exist in DB then skip import

Tags: php, mysql, database, import, codeigniter-3

application/controllers/Home.php

This is part of my function for import csv/xslt to database using codeIgnier 3 and php spreadsheet library.

```
function import_excel()
    {
        $this->load->helper('file');

        /* Allowed MIME(s) File */
        $file_mimes = array(
            'application/octet-stream', 
            'application/vnd.ms-excel', 
            'application/x-csv', 
            'text/x-csv', 
            'text/csv', 
            'application/csv', 
            'application/excel', 
            'application/vnd.msexcel', 
            'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'
        );

        if(isset($_FILES['uploadFile']['name']) && in_array($_FILES['uploadFile']['type'], $file_mimes)) {

            $array_file = explode('.', $_FILES['uploadFile']['name']);
            $extension  = end($array_file);

            if('csv' == $extension) {
                $reader = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\Csv();
            } else {
                $reader = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\Xlsx();
            }

            $spreadsheet = $reader->load($_FILES['uploadFile']['tmp_name']);
            $sheet_data  = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet(0)->toArray();
            $array_data  = [];

            for($i = 1; $i < count($sheet_data); $i++) {
                $data = array(
                    'name'       => $sheet_data[$i]['0'],
                    'price'      => $sheet_data[$i]['1'],
                    'qty'        => $sheet_data[$i]['2'],
                    'input_date' => $sheet_data[$i]['3'],
                    'sku' => $sheet_data[$i]['4']
                );
                $array_data[] = $data;
            }
            
            if($array_data != '') {
                $this->home_model->insert_transaction_batch($array_data);
            }
            $this->modal_feedback('success', 'Success', 'Data Imported', 'OK');
        } else {
            $this->modal_feedback('error', 'Error', 'Import failed', 'Try again');
        }
        redirect('/');
    }
```

Can anybody help me add a rule to this function: if the row `sku` with the given number exists in the database, then skip the record and do not import.

So for summary:

in csv file I have
sku: 72323
sku: 847233

in database now is one record with sku: 72323. Then skip this row and import only sku: 847233

Comment: Create a unique index on the SKU and change the INSERT ...... to INSERT IGNORE

Comment: @Bernd Buffen, this crate unique index on the sku - working correct. But im not sure with this function how to edit to insert ignore "function insert_transaction_batch($data)
    {
      $this->db->insert_batch($this->tbl_transaction, $data);
    }"